# Twitter Bot: Get access token for another account without 3-legged OAuth flow?

Tags: api, rest, twitter, bots, twitter-oauth

I am in control of three twitter accounts: One is my main account, the other two are supposed to automatically post content via a bot. I created the bot logic and added it to Twitter's development tools and I can easily use it to post to my main account.

Now I need to add the access tokens for my two secondary accounts. My question is - what's the easiest way to do this.

As far as I can see, Twitter only enables one way to do this: [3-legged OAuth flow](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens). It is not too complex, but it seems to me to require setting up a mock website with callback url, which seems like too much considering I only need to generate two api tokens. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some alternative ways to generate access token and access token secret for OAuth 1.0A via command line tools which allow you to use the “PIN-based” OAuth flow.

One example would be Twitter’s own [`twurl`](https://github.com/twitter/twurl) tool for API testing, which requires you to also have Ruby installed. This will let you authenticate a user account (it still pops open a window onto twitter.com to have you do the authentication) and stores them into the `~/.twurlrc` file in your home directory. There is also [`tw-oob-oauth-cli`](https://github.com/smaeda-ks/tw-oob-oauth-cli) which is a standalone app for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing something. The reason this is required is to force users have a browser they trust open and see that they are on `https://twitter.com/`, so they can trust that it's a safe place to put in their password.